# Using a simple scanner, reading a string with spaces, how come .trim() method isn't working?

Tags: java, string, trim

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[] sArray;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a Palindrome : ");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        s = s.trim();

        sArray = new char[s.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            sArray[i] = s.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(sArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the difference between your expectations and the result?

Comment: @thejh :Im typing for example   STR  ING.... expecting  STRING back..

Comment: Have you tried this -> s = s.replaceAll(\\w+); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trim doesn't work how you expect it to.  `trim()` only removes whitespace from the ends of the string.

The [documentation for `trim()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29):

> Returns a copy of the string, with **leading** and **trailing** whitespace omitted.

To remove all whitespace try the following instead of calling `trim()`:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

This uses a very simple regular expression to remove all whitespace anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 2):

The `trim` function removes *leading and trailing* spaces, not all spaces.

If you want to remove all spaces, you can call `s = s.replaceAll(" ", "")`.

Comment: oh ok so how would i get to my expected result?

Answer (score 0):

great answer jjnguy and slals

I now use

```
myinput = myEditTextbox.getText().toString;
myinput = myinput.replaceAll("\\S+", "");
```

to clean out all spaces accidentally left in an edittext box by the user.
It also directed me to learn about regular expressions that I didn't know about.
Thanks